# How to calculate the linear regression result with coefficient and intercept in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, matrix, linear-regression

I built a linear regression model and the corresponding coefficients for each feature are like this:

```
regressor.coef_

array([[ 0.10152211,  0.09513825,  0.09252367, -0.31748762, -0.16836985,
    -0.06827792, -0.09545832, -0.11869289,  0.03285754, -0.28077261,
    -0.17607958, -0.53094975,  0.47035754, -0.27898882]])
```

My features are like this:

```
features = [
  'N/A', 
'Female', 
'Male', 
'Third Gender', 
'Marketing',
'Finance',
'IT',
'HR',
'Audit',
'Promotion',
'Legal',
'Operations',
'CEO',
'Owner'
]
```

Instead of input the formula manually like this:

```
Y = a*x1+b*x2+c*x3+......+Intercept
```

Once the coefficients and intercept changed, I need to type again.
Is there a better way in Python code to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your features as numpy array. Then your formula becomes simple dot product of features and regression coefficients:

```
np.dot(X, regressor.coef_)
```

Probably even better way is to use .predict method of regressor if uses sklearn API.

```
regressor.predict(X)
```